# Jquery не фильтрует код?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Стоит задача получить значение из двух мест на странице, значения к примеру 5 и 1 000  ₽ перемножить, получить сумму к примеру 5000, добавить пробел и  ₽, что бы получилось 5 000  ₽ и заменить первоначальную цену. Вот где умножение и добавление пробела после первого символа, все ломается. Как поправить?

```js
// find elements
$(document).on('click', '.col-minus', function() {
  var colsh = $('.popup2').find("input[name='quantity']").val();
  colsh = (colsh.replace(/[^0-9]/gim, ''));
  var cost = $('.popup2').find('.getc').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text();
  var filtr = (cost.replace(/[^0-9]/gim, ''));
  var zam = filtr * colsh;
  zam = (zam.replace(/(.)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1 '));
  $('.popup2').find('.getc').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').html(zam + '&nbsp;&nbsp;₽');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup2">
  <div class="woocommerce-variation-price getc">
    <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>1 000&nbsp;
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"> ₽</span></bdi>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="quantity">
    <span class="col-minus">-</span>
    <input type="number" id="quantity_5fe8e57d9cd26" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол-во" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
    <span class="col-plus">+</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: забыл уточнить, что действие должно происходить по нажатию на кнопку "-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас умножение даёт число, но вы используете с ним метод строки `.replace()`. Попробуйте так:

```
var zam = String(filtr * colsh);
```

Comment: да, заработало) большое спасибо